# Turn PHP echo into if/else

Tags: php

I have a PHP echo like this, code below:

```
<?php echo($row['buildingdesignsvo']); ?>
```

How do I turn this into a If/Else based on the contents of the echo?  If the echo for example is either value1 or value2 it displays a link like this `<a href="">Link</a>` if it does not contain either value it displays Nothing found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($row['buildingdesignsvo'] == 'value1') {
  // do something
  echo '<a href="">Link</a>';
} else {
  // do something else
}
```

Comment: He wants to determine if the value you contains something, not if it is equal to something.

Answer (score 1):

you should use ternary operator

```
echo ($row['buildingdesignsvo'] == 'value1')?( '<a href="">Link</a>'):();
```

I didn't test it, but somehow like this

Answer (score 0):

I assume you will be echoing some value

```
echo $value
if($value==something){
  echo 'this';
}else{
  echo 'that';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo(in_array($row['buildingdesignsvo'], ['value1','value2'])? '<a href="">Link</a>': "Nothing Found" ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question I assume that you want to check to see whether `$row['buildingdesignsvo']` equals 1 of two variables (`$value1` and `$value2`) and then `echo` "Nothing found" if not...

A simple `if` statement:

```
<?php 
if($row['buildingdesignsvo'] == $value1){
    echo "<a href='link1.php'>Link 1</a>";
}
else if($row['buildingdesignsvo'] == $value2){
    echo "<a href='link2.php'>Link 2</a>";
}
else{
    echo "Nothing found";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    if($row['buildingdesignsvo'] == 'value1'){
        echo '<a href="#">Link1</a>';
    }
    else{
        echo 'default value';
    }
?>
```

It might be better to use a function or even a switch case.

```
<?php
    function check(){
       if($row['buildingdesignsvo'] == 'value1'){
            $data = '<a href="#">Link1</a>';
        }
        else{
            $data = 'default value';
        }
        return $data;
    }
    $check = check();
    echo $check;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually want to do the if else on the contents of the echo, you want to do it on the contents of the array:

```
<?php
if ($row['buildingdesignsvo'] == $value1){
    //If first value - Echo link
}
else if($row['buildingdesignsvo'] == $value2){
    //If second value - Echo link
}
else{
    //Doesn't match so echo 'Nothing Found'
}  
?>
```

If the link is the same for both cases you can further simplify it by combining the first two cases with an OR

```
<?php
if (($row['buildingdesignsvo'] == $value1) || ($row['buildingdesignsvo'] == $value2)) {
    //If first or second value - Echo link
}
else{
    //Doesn't match so echo 'Nothing Found'
} 
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Store it in a Var first, then check the value of it and echo it if so..

```
<?php 
$var = $row['buildingdesignsvo'];
if ($var == 'value'){
    echo $var;
}else { 
    //something to do;
 }
 ?>
```

EDIT: after your edit :P

To check if it contains a string, use strstr() or stristr() for un-casesensitive.

```
<?php 
$var = $row['buildingdesignsvo'];
if (stristr($var, 'value')){
    echo "<a href=''>link</a>";
}else { 
   echo "not foundr";
 }
 ?>
```